# Azure Rest API PUT Block Blob Returns "The specified resource does not exist." CORS

Tags: rest, azure, cors, azure-storage

I am trying to upload a file to Azure Blob storage.
For some reason when I try to put a new block blob on in the storage it tells me the resource does not exist. I am sure it is something silly I am missing.

According to the documentation:

The Put Blob operation creates a new block blob or page blob, or updates the content of an existing block blob.
Updating an existing block blob overwrites any existing metadata on the blob. Partial updates are not supported with Put Blob; the content of the existing blob is overwritten with the content of the new blob. To perform a partial update of the content of a block blob, use the Put Block List (REST API) operation.

CORS is setup and that seems okay.

When I do a preflight and get this:

```
Request URL:https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/test/image.png
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
-----------------
OPTIONS /test/image.png HTTP/1.1
Host: <account>.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://www.<site>.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.<site>.com/azure/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Response Headers
----------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Blob Service Version 1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 0d372e95-1524-460a-ab9c-7973d42a7070
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.<site>.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 36000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Thu, 27 Feb 2014 22:43:52 GMT
```

But when I make the PUT request these are the results.

```
Request URL:https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/test/image.png
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:404 The specified resource does not exist.

Request Headers
-----------------
PUT /test/image.png HTTP/1.1
Host: <account>.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 22787
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
x-ms-blob-content-disposition: attachment; filename = "image.png"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: image/png
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
x-ms-version: 2013-08-15
Origin: http://www.<site>.com
x-ms-date: Thu, 27 Feb 2014 23:19:19 GMT
Referer: http://www.<site>.com/azure/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Response Headers
----------------
HTTP/1.1 404 The specified resource does not exist.
Content-Length: 223
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Blob Service Version 1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: d5a60c8b-356a-44ff-93af-0ea720b5591f
x-ms-version: 2013-08-15
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-ms-request-id,Server
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.<site>.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Thu, 27 Feb 2014 23:22:42 GMT
```

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: The test project is at [http://www.rezstreamapps.com/azure](http://www.rezstreamapps.com/azure). I am working with the demo from [http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/](http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/)

Comment: Please include a minimum-reproducible code-sample to understand exactly how you're attempting to upload the file. Otherwise, it's impossible to help you.